# CircleCI - how to download dependency only if not cached

Tags: caching, libreoffice, circleci

**in brief**

When using circleci to run unittest, I have to download & install LibreOffice. How can we do the download only if not cached?

p.s. Also posted on circleci support [here](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/requests/61658)

**details**

LibreOffice download & install often takes 30+ seconds to complete.

So I intend to cache it using **save_cache** feature [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#save_cache)

My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=CircleCI%20-%20how%20to%20download%20dependency%20only%20if%20not%20cached&oq=CircleCI%20-%20how%20to%20download%20dependency%20only%20if%20not%20cached&aqs=chrome..69i57.403j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) leads me to **when steps** [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#the-when-step-requires-version-21), though the guide there is not clear about how to check if a cache key exists.

I put the marker HOW_TO in the .circleci/config.yml below snippet

```
      - restore_cache:
          key: cache-libreoffice

      - when:
          condition: <<HOW_TO check if cache key exists >>
          steps:
            - run:
                name: install atlas Pipfile
                command: |
                  mkdir -p /tmp/libreoffice
                  cd /tmp/libreoffice
                    wget https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/6.3.3/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_6.3.3_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

      - save_cache:
          key: cache-libreoffice
          paths:  # the paths to save to cache entry
            - /tmp/libreoffice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As circleci official support seems to give less helpful hints for the question, my workaround is to use [custom docker image](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/custom-images/) and have those dependencies installed there.